Why a CNAME cannot exist with other records that have the same name as the CNAME?
I have read various blogs  that a CNAME cannot coexist with other records that have the same name as the CNAME record.
I have not found a good  example explaining the problem.
Here is an example from the blog:

CNAME records cannot coexist with other records that have the same FQDN as the CNAME record because they effectively overwrite all other records with the same FQDN.


For example, a CNAME record FQDN is example.com, and you want to create an A record FQDN example.com. This is not allowed because the A record FQDN is identical to the CNAME record FQDN, rendering the A record purposeless.

I do not find the example clear enough for me to understand the problem.
I am trying to understand what the explanation means.
Imagine I have configured:



Domain name
TTL
Class
Record type
Value




aliasname.example.com
300
IN
CNAME
name.example.com


name.example.com
300
IN
A
10.0.0.1



What happens in such a configuration?
EDIT: I stand corrected by answers that my above example is correct/valid.
Putting an incorrect/invalid configuration below. The above example came from my wrong understanding of text examples lacking  table illustrations.



Domain name
TTL
Class
Record type
Value




name.example.com
300
IN
CNAME
othername.example.com


name.example.com
300
IN
A
10.0.0.1



My understanding is that the latter configuration is invalid because according to RFCs the CNAME is used first and the A record is never used.
Am I right regarding the cause of incorrectness of the latter table?
Or in general what happens in the case of the latter configuration?

Does this answer your question? Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?

Your last example is invalid not because "something is used first". It is invalid because it violates the logic behind the CNAME.
The logic I am talking about is that CNAME defines the name to be an alias of some other name, which is then referred to as a canonical name, "cname" being abbreviation of that. The record alias CNAME canonical-name literally says: "alias is the other form of canonical-name". It's very much like to say: "Bob is the other form of Robert". It is absurd to add: "and also alias is something else", it wouldn't make sense, at least, in computing. It doesn't fit into the data model, so it is explicitly disallowed by the RFC.
The same reasoning stands behind CNAME at apex of the zone: an apex must define at least two records, SOA and NS, which is already at conflict with the requirement that CNAME must appear alone. (Initially I thought to vote for this question to be closed as a duplicate of the linked one, because that answer really answers this one too; however, it seems this is another, more broad, question, and it would be more sense to do it in the opposite direction.)
There was an update to this rule when DNSSEC was introduced. Signing records must appear together with CNAME to certify it's validity in a signed zone. But no other record can. (RFC 2181 says "may", but the record won't really work without signing in a signed zone.)

That the CNAME cannot coexist with other record types relates to this:



Domain name
TTL
Class
Record type
Value




host.example.com
300
IN
CNAME
fqdn.example.com


host.example.com
300
IN
A
192.0.2.1



NOT the scenario you described. The reason for it being invalid appears somewhat arbitrary but I believe it is a requirement of the RFCs.
Your described scenario is quite valid - and widely used. E.g.



Domain name
TTL
Class
Record type
Value




service1.example.com
300
IN
CNAME
reverseproxy.example.com


service2.example.com
300
IN
CNAME
reverseproxy.example.com


service3.example.com
300
IN
CNAME
reverseproxy.example.com


reverseproxy.example.com
300
IN
A
192.0.2.1




Which of the records of the former table in the answer is never used then?
Or cannot it pass some validation upon update to be saved?
Does it depend on certain DNS server implementation?

The first table I described above? If it is not allowed by the RFC, then no DNS server should implement it - however not all DNS servers are correct all the time (e.g. bind used to allow multiple records for the apex domain). It is possible to have multiple records of the same type with different values - this is important for round-robin DNS  where, in the absence of weighting factors defined elsewhere, the records returned in response to a query are always in a random order.

Do bear in mind that if you find your DNS server allows you to do something which is not allowed by the rules, then 1) they may fix this at some point in the future 2) how clients will interpret the data is not predictable.

Your example is valid.
What's not valid is



Domain name
ttl
Class
Record type
Value




cname.example.com
300
IN
CNAME
foo.example.org


cname.example.com
300
IN
A
192.0.2.1




Quote from the horse's mouth, RFC 1034:

The domain system provides such a feature using the canonical name
(CNAME) RR.  A CNAME RR identifies its owner name as an alias, and
specifies the corresponding canonical name in the RDATA section of the
RR.  If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its
aliases cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached
CNAME can be used without checking with an authoritative server for
other RR types.

